# C++ memory management paradigms

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management, stl

I'm moving from C to C++11 and trying to figure out the memory management paradigm for C++11 programs (or any modern languages with built-in exceptions). Specifically, I'm having a crack at game development where running out of memory is a real concern.

In C, I'm using to checking the return value of malloc; and generally use custom allocators.

With C++, I'm quite confused; though I like how the STL containers were built allowing custom allocators. Since the STL containers all manage their own memory, simply adding an element to a vector could throw a `std::bad_alloc`. How do I guard against such things? I have heard wrapping all throwing calls in try/catch blocks can be prohibitively expensive.

However, allowing the exception to travel up the callstack would allow in a bunch of functions that would not fully execute, and would lead to some really tricky code. i.e. if `A->B->C->D` is a callstack, `D` throws, and `A` catches, then `B`, `C`, and `D` could have potentially created some weird problems by not being able to finish execution normally.

Additionally, the `nothrow` argument seems to allow very C-like code; though I now don't see the benefit over a plain malloc.

What are some best practices out there for writing exception-safe C++ code that guards against out-of-memory issues?

**edit:** [A relevant answer on progammers.stackexchange arguing for exception-less C++ design in consoles.](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/113481) Not sure if these arguments still apply to the [8th generation consoles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_video_game_consoles_(eighth_generation))

Comment: You know that certain platforms will happily return a non-null pointer from `malloc()` and still fail once you actually *use* that memory (because the virtual memory handler only *then* realizes it's out of swap space)?

Comment: @DevSolar Ya I've been told that this is a possibility. Luckily I've never run into this issue - not sure what I'd do in such a scenario other than keep around a big enough buffer to deallocate in such a scenario to be able to have some wiggle room to exit appropriately

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My answer will be geared more towards game development since that is my background and that is part of what you are interested in. Different types of applications will have different requirements.

Games generally allocate all dynamic memory up front and stick within that budget.  Consoles in particular have hard memory limits and most games will want to use all of it.

There's a few reasons for allocating everything up front.

One, performance. Memory allocation is slow. You want to avoid it at all costs. If you allocate everything up front, you can then write custom, high performance memory allocators like Pool Allocators, Stack Allocators, etc, that just grab memory from your pre-allocated buffer. It's important to choose the best allocator for the task at hand.

Two, you'll know quickly if there isn't enough memory for your game. In development, you'll crash if you run out of memory and will need to adjust usage, but the final release shouldn't crash because you've allocated up front and stuck within your memory budgets.

For exceptions, many (but not all) games disable exceptions, again for performance reasons. In fact some console compilers don't even support exceptions.  Then you will either need to use an STL library with no exceptions, or implement your own containers.  Many game teams choose to implement their own for performance reasons as well as to better integrate them with custom memory allocators.

That said, dynamic memory allocation, STL, and exceptions are probably perfectly fine for smaller personal projects/games, but keep in mind what will be necessary for large, high performance, real-time games.

For exception safety, I would definitely use [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization). That is its purpose. Also I would recommend using smart pointers like `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` for memory management. Coupled with RAII, if your constructors throw, memory will be freed.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've seen those arguments for allocating memory upfront before - and I totally agree. I *did not* know that exceptions were *that* opposed to in games though; very interesting. Ya I think I need more experience with RAII, seems like a good idiom/practice to follow for situations just like this

Comment: Although I worked for a games-oriented company I didn't know that either. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: I also recommend to read about Electonic Arts STL: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2271.html

Comment: Disabling exception for performance reasons is stupid. If done properly, exceptions can outperform error code (c way) of handling errors.

Comment: @kevinarpe ya I've seen links to that before - I'll check it out! Thanks for posting

Comment: @BЈовић, thanks for your input, but I wouldn't consider professional game developers to be stupid. Consoles have a history of none to poor exception handling and so are usually disabled by default. Throwing exceptions are expensive and will impact frame rate. Actual game play should not encounter errors (except for things like network drops or certain types of user input). If a non-recoverable error occurs, it's often better to crash so the programmers can get a core dump and fix the issue.

Comment: @megadan Ya I've just been reading into this. Exceptions seem to be extremely slow in the *exceptional* case - and still add some slight overhead in the normal case, even with "zero-cost" exceptions.

Comment: And error checking code doesn't add overhead? Are we to believe that adding 4 or 5 lines of error checking code everywhere you need to worry about an exceptional return value, just so that you can pass it back to your own caller, doesn't add overhead in terms of code size and locality? Those lines have to be loaded and jumped over in the non-exceptional case.

Comment: @Rob K My comments are specifically for game development. Performance critical code isn't littered with error codes and return checking, just like it can't be filled with thrown exceptions. Released games aren't supposed to fail. If they do, it usually means they must exit immediately. Most failures must be handled during development.

Comment: The article kevinarpe posted about EA has a good section about disabling exception handling in games. This is from EA themselves. Again this is game specific, and it doesn't necessarily carry over to best practices for other domains.

Answer (score 6):

Use destructors to clean up automatically when scopes are exited. That's called **RAII**, *Resource Acquisition Is Initializion*, although the acronym is not exactly the best one could devise. All the standard containers etc. clean up automatically.

In languages like C# and Java which are based on garbage collection, you instead pepper the code with `try` blocks and “using” statements. Java just got that (part of the `try` syntax IIRC); it's been in C# from the beginning (keyword `using`); in Python it's called `with`; and C++ doesn't have it and doesn't need it. I once created a `WITH` macro for C++, a clever little hack, thinking I would be using it all the time, but I haven't used it once except just to try it out right after creating it: in C++ RAII does it all.

Summing up: use RAII, i.e., use destructors, and just let those exceptions propagate.

---

Regarding memory exhaustion, ordinarily that's just regarded as “we're done for”, nothing to do except terminate as orderly as possible.

But it doesn't hurt to maybe set aside a little buffer which can deallocated when memory is exhausted, so as to have some working memory for cleanup-work.

---

C++ doesn't differentiate between *hard* exceptions (fatal like e.g. memory exhaustion) and *soft* exceptions (general failures that are not fatal).

Comment: +1. This explains how the call stack from the question A->B->C-D gets cleaned up: destructors in D,C and B run even if D throws. This is the cleanup equivalent of Java's `finally`, but in C++ the cleanup is specified in each type, not each function using that type. This is a net saving.

Comment: Agreed, I like the RAII idea. Thanks for the post Cheers

Comment: Another thing that makes RAII better than using a `finally` block, without RAII every place you use an instance of an object you must have a finally block that does the exact same thing to clean up after that object, which violates the Don't Repeat Yourself (DRY) principle.